# In the last for loop I will to exclude execution of loop when Y=0 is met. How to I do it?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math

epsr = float(input('Enter the relative permittivity of waveguide material ')) #permittivity
mur=float(input('Enter the relative permeabilty of waveguide material ')) # permeability
f0= float(input('Enter the operating frequency ')) #operating frequency
LWG= float(input('Enter the length of the waveguide ')) #length of waveguide
rho=float(input('Enter the conductivity of the waveguide material '))# Conductivity
thickness=float(input('Enter the thickness of the waveguide ')) #Thickness
c= 300000000 #Speed of light
lamda0=c/f0 #wavelength in free space
mu0=1.25663706e-6 #permeability of free space
eps0= 8.854187817e-12 # permittivity of free space
k=2*math.pi*math.sqrt(mur*epsr)/lamda0 ##wavenumber
print(k)
N= float(input('Enter the number of slots ')) #No of slots
ln= float(input('Enter the length of the slot ')) #Length of the slot
xn= float(input('Enter the offset of the slot ')) #offset of the slot
#Width of the waveguide
a=float(input('Enter the width of the waveguide ie long dimension  '))
#Height of the waveguide 
b=float(input('Enter the height of the waveguide ie short dimension '))
Z0=120*math.pi #impedence of free space
print(Z0)
AOS=(a*b-(a-2*thickness)*(b-2*thickness)) #area of cross section of the waveguide
print(AOS)
G0=rho*AOS/LWG #Conductance of the waveguide
fc=c/(2*a) #cut off frequency
nsa = 1/N #normalized slot admittance
beta=2*math.pi*f0*math.sqrt(1-(pow((fc/f0),2)))/c #factor beta
fn=(math.cos(beta*ln)-math.cos(k*ln))*math.sin(math.pi*xn/a)/math.sin(k*ln)
K1=-1j*math.sqrt(8*(a/b))/(pow(math.pi,2)*Z0*G0*(beta/k))
#K1=pow(math.pi,2)*Z0*G0*(beta/k)
nsv=nsa/(K1*fn*math.sin(k*ln))
lamdag=lamda0/math.sqrt(1-pow((fc/f0),2))
theta = np.linspace(0, 180, 1001)
G=[]
AF=[]
F=[]
print(theta)
for i in  range(1001):
    if math.sin(theta[i])==0:
        G.insert(i,0)
    else:
        p=(math.cos(k*ln*math.cos(theta[i]))- 
math.cos(k*ln))/math.sin(theta[i])
        G.insert(i,p)
for q in  range(1001):
    if math.cos(theta[q])==0:
        AF.insert(q,0)
    else:
        m=pow(math.e,(1j*N*k*lamdag/2*math.cos(theta[i])))
        AF.insert(q,m)
for n in  range(1001):
        h=N*nsv*G[n]*AF[n]
        Y=h.real
        if
        Y=0
        print(Y)
        p=math.log10(Y)
        F.insert(n,p)
```

This is a code to develop the radiation pattern of a rectangular array. I get an error if the log encounters 0 as log10(0) is undefined. Any help in the above topic will be highly appreciated.

The inputs used are in the following sequence:
`1.46`, `1`, `10000000000`, `0.5`, `35380000`, `0.05`, `4`, `0.05`, `0.005`, `0.2`, `0.1`.

Comment: The last `for` loop of your code is syntactically wrong. Please fix it. Also, remove all unnecessary code.

Comment: as a general advice for debugging and to help your questions being better  received, read [mcve] (the missing part here is "minimal")

Answer (score 3):

I think you are saying "if Y not equal to 0, then...", which programmatically is:

`if Y != 0`

Updating your loop. I'm guessing you want to avoid the insert into `F` as well when Y is 0.

```
for n in  range(1001):
        h=N*nsv*G[n]*AF[n]
        Y=h.real
        if Y!=0:
            print(Y)
            p=math.log10(Y)
            F.insert(n,p)
```

Answer (score 0):

This part of your last loop

```
    if
    Y=0
    print(Y)
    p=math.log10(Y)
    F.insert(n,p)
```

is not syntactically correct; you probably meant

```
    if Y==0:
        print(Y)
    p = math.log10(Y)
    F.insert(n, p)
```

But the `log10(0)` will still be evaluated, so add the `else` branch:

```
    if Y==0:
        print(Y)
    else:
        p = math.log10(Y)
        F.insert(n, p)
```

and if you want print nonzero values of `Y`, too, put the `print()` function just before `if`:

```
    print(Y)
    if Y==0:
        pass             # do nothing, but syntactically something here is needed
    else:
        p = math.log10(Y)
        F.insert(n, p)
```

But in this case, you don't need two branches, so only negate your condition:

```
    print(Y)
    if Y != 0:
        p = math.log10(Y)
        F.insert(n, p)
```

or - as the nonzero values are in the `if` statement evaluated as `True`:

```
    print(Y)
    if Y:
        p = math.log10(Y)
        F.insert(n, p)
```

---

Note that I did some small style changes in your code in concordance with [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).